# How to set a bit in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have the following header structure

```
class MacHeaderBase extends FieldsChunk
{
    MacAddress srcAdd;
    MacAddress destAdd;
    MacTypes type; 
    bool controlbit; //a single bit
      
}
```

In .cc file, i need to set the `controlbit` as 1 and reset it to 0 where needed.

Can anyone please suggest me the syntax how to set `controlbit` as 1 and reset it to 0 in OMNeT++?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message compiler in OMNeT++ will automatically generate methods for setting and getting every field of the message. The names of these methods contain `set` + capitalized name of the field, and `get` + capitalized name of the field, respectively.
So if `msg` is pointer to an instance of `MacHeaderBase` one can set `controlbit` this way:

```
msg->setControlbit(true);
```

An example of reading `controlbit`:

```
bool x = msg->getControlbit();
```

By the way: you have declared `controlbit` as a bool so you should avoid assigning integer to it.

Comment: Thanks Jerzy. If I declare ```controlbit``` as ```int controlbit @unit(b)```, is it the right way to declare a single bit? In that case can I write ```msg->setControlbit(1)``` to set a bit? Also, can you suggest me the syntax how to read ```controlbit``` value?

Comment: Yes, you can declare:`int controlbit;` but without unit. Then you can use `msg->setControlbit(1);`. I have added an example of reading to the answer.

Comment: Jerzy, I am getting the following error with ```hdr->setMorebit(1)```  syntax: Error "passing ‘const inet::EXMacHeaderBase’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         hdr->setMorebit(1);

Comment: There is no `morebit` in your question. I suggest opening a new question for this problem with [mcve].

Comment: This is only name change. ```controlbit``` is renamed with```morebit``` but the syntax is same

Comment: Jerzy, I posted a new question regarding this error. Can you please answer that?